# Find matching strings in txt file using pattern from other txt file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, findstr

I'm trying to search a txt file for a string match using another file which contains over 1000 lines of strings.

I have tried findstr using batch file but the search stops if the string contains spaces.

```
for /F %%i in (PatternList.txt) do (
echo Files containing %%i
findstr /C:%%i Data.txt
)
```

I have then tried to use Powershell:

So far I have this, but I think I need to loop somehow through the PatternList.txt and then use the list to find each string in the Data.txt.

```
$file_data = Get-Content C:\temp\test\PatternList.txt
Get-Content C:\temp\test\Data.txt | Where-Object { $_.Contains($file_data) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Select-String` to search for more than one pattern.

```
$file_data = Get-Content -Path D:\sample\patternlist.txt | Where-Object {$_}
Select-String -Path D:\sample\Source.txt -Pattern @('(?!)'; $file_data)
```

To deal with empty lines in the pattern list file you can use an added `Where-Object` and to deal with an empty file we can use the recommendation from Mathias.
Kudos to Mathias. ;-)

Comment: Getting this error now: Select-String : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Pattern' because it is an empty string.

Comment: The file should have one pattern per line with no empty lines in it.

Comment: You could work around an empty list by always supplying a pattern that won't match anything: `-Pattern @('(?!)';$file_data)`

Comment: But that wouldn't help either when you have an empty line in the pattern list file. Or did I get something wrong?